# Bluetooth Low Energy with iOS 6

Tags: ios6, bluetooth, core-bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm trying to make a new app that talks to a bluetooth low energy chip. I have never played around with bluetooth or BLE before, so I'm trying to learn as much as I can about it. I know that I have to implement Apple's Core Bluetooth framework, and from there I have a few very basic questions.

1. Is the code for writing apps with classic bluetooth the same as apps with BLE, or are they different?
2. What's the deal with AT commands, I tried reading a bit into it but are those something I have to mix with Objective-C while making a call to the device?
3. Central and peripheral. I noticed that when you are making two devices talk to each other, one has to be central and one peripheral. Lets say I make an app that turns on a light via a bluetooth low energy chip. Would the iPhone be the peripheral, and the chip / light be the central?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Bluetooth "classic" and Bluetooth Low Energy don't work the same way. Bluetooth Low Energy works with Peripheral->Service(s)->Characteristic(s) (it's like a tree)...

    There are a few videos at the WWDC 2012 session (from the Portal iOS Developers) dealing with Bluetooth Low Energy and the CoreBluetooth.framework.
   There is also sample code (CoreBluetooth Temperature Sensor) from Apple.
   Apps to play with and free : LightBlue & BLE Utility, which can convert them into Peripheral/Central and interact...

Comment: +1 for WWDC 2012 session videos. Just watched them yesterday and they explain a lot, including the nomenclature of Central and Peripheral.